# Static ML model or Time-Series? How to model/predict a Binary target when I have time variant features but most features are constant?

Tags: time-series, classification, boosting

I  have been working with Real World data from patients. I have a dataset with information about 10million patients; Collected over a span of varying duration (5 to 20 years).

- What I am predicting is a binary risk (or maybe the probability of that risk);
- Most features are constant (family history, smoker (y/n)...), but,
- I have some time-dependant features (e.g., weight, cholesterol value, glucose value...),
- (Also, these features were collected at different time points, i.e., for some patients, we have semestral info, for some patients, we have 2 measures in 15 years)
- So far I have been predicting my target considering my features are static (by averaging values, or using the most recent one) using XGBoost Classifier or other classifiers.
- Could I try to use a time series for this case? Or just stick to ML Classifiers and try to incorporate the progression of values in another way?
- Has someone had a similar problem?

Cheers!

Comment: What are you trying to predict? (disease, progression, treatment, mortality, recovery, or ... ?)

Comment: thanks, I edited it. What I am predicting is a binary risk (or maybe the probability of that risk)